# ExtJs layout + Window

Tags: layout, extjs, window, hbox

While adding component dynamically, 'this.container is null' is displayed in firebug.

I have a window with some combo boxes say combo1, combo2, combo3 and a label. Based on the selection value of combo3 the 'label' field is removed and replaced with combobox or text field. i do this my using

```
form.items.removeAt(4);
form.items.insert(4, newItem); #here newItem can be combox/textfield
form.doLayout();
```

The form resides inside a panel.

When above lines are execueted. 'this.container is null' is displayed and component fails to insert/add in appropiate position.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the layout manager that you are using?

Comment: Do not call doLayout() if you're using ExtJS4 btw.
Does the removing work?

Comment: First of all use `ext-all-debug.js` or `ext-all-dev.js` source file to see all debug flow in Firebug. You will see on which step does error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment those lines line-by-line to see which one produces error like

```
form.items.removeAt(4);
//form.items.insert(4, newItem); #here newItem can be combox/textfield
//form.doLayout();

form.items.removeAt(4);
form.items.insert(4, newItem); #here newItem can be combox/textfield
//form.doLayout();

form.items.removeAt(4);
form.items.insert(4, newItem); #here newItem can be combox/textfield
form.doLayout();
```

Your problem could take place because of inserted/replaced object is no yet prepared when you try to insert it. Give us your newItem initilization code.

**Upd**

Or you can wrap your changing components (label, combobox, textfields) in a panel with `card` [layout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.layout.CardLayout). And on change of combo3 simply select exact `card` in that panel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error occurrs in form.doLayout(). The component gets inserted successfully. But while doLayout() the error is displayed.

Comment: What is your ExtJS version? What about using `ext-all-debug.js` or `ext-all-dev.js`? Give us debug info from firebug.

Comment: Using Extjs 3.4. Using ext-all-debug.js, the errors occurs in render: function (conatiner, position)() at the line position=this.container.dom.addChild[position]

Comment: The error the thrown at 11362: position = this.container.dom.childNodes[position];

in ext-all-debug.js

Comment: And without `doLayout()` invoke you can't solve your task? Try to simply `replace()` your label with another component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i found a temporary solution similar to your updated answer. Intially i will have the combo3/textfield hidden and based on selection from combo2, the combo3/textfield will be set to visible.

Comment: i cannot accept a answer here for the question asked. May be your answers will work, but it does not help me in my framework. Any how your comment on replace() has given me the hint for solution of hide and replace. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be modifying the underlying items collection. Use the remove/insert methods on the container.